# design choice for a data structure customizable by the user?

Tags: c#, database-design, architecture

I'm planning to build an application that must allow the user to set up its own data model (i.e. create fields, data structure, etc.) dynamically.

I'm facing several technical possibilities, all having drawbacks. :

1. in admin screens, update the SQL schema of the DB to reflect the changes.

   - I fear this is a very bad idea because of the permissions the application must have on the DB. Moreover, if every click a new sql schema must be applied, I imagine I will run direct on a hole. This is the approach I've seen on most application customizable by the user.
2. create in DB schema a set of generic extra columns and hope there is enough columns for the complex data models.

   - this will quickly can be a functionnal limitation if I can't allow more than X columns in my app
3. store in a single table all items with an ID column and a Xml column to store the user-defined columns.

   - this approach may remove the previously mentioned drawacks because the sql schema will remain static, but as EF (which I was hoping to be able to use) does not know how to manage xml data type, I will have to end up with either manual SqlCommand with XML function, or writing a custom EF provider, which I imagine will be quite a lot of work.
   - This the approach chosen by Microsoft for SharePoint... this let me think it's the better one (or at least the less bad)
4. create a "properties" table with basically a itemId column, a property name column and a property value column

   - this approach implies a very very large table (X items * Y properties per item)
   - I will have to store my values in plain text, even if it's numerical for example.

My requirements are :

- keep the code maintainable, unit testable and all fashioned technics
- have a responsive application with large amount of data
- have an as secured as possible application
- allow the users to fully customize their application (create custom view with filter / sort on user properties).

I feel the choice of the correct design must be the good one now, because it would be very hard to change this latter.

Any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: Nice idea and might be useful but you mean dynamically it does includes deletion of field/property?

Comment: @eSPiYa: yes... "fully customizable"... only some fields are required (id, creator, etc.) and other must be add/deleted/updated/etc. by users

Comment: If you are interested in a way to make use of an XML data-type, I could give you an example how to make it work in EF. I like the idea of a custom view being serialized to XML.

Comment: @J. Tihon: yes of course I'm interested :)

Comment: @Steve B: I have an idea but before I was able to post it, I found out that AdaTheDev's suggestion is a lot more better. This is the first time I've heard about NoSQL but based on Wikipedia's entry about it, it is a lot faster than RDBMS and Facebook is already using it with a massive 50TB of data store. Just learn how to use it and also perform volume testing aside from unit testing because this is a new technology, you don't want to crash your app because of massive stored data.

Comment: @Stebe B: I've created an example, but it still is somewhat to big for a discussion on data-structures. Especially since NoSQL databases do a pretty good job in this sort of things. Let me just state, that if you want a complex object serialized to XML in the database using EF, you can have it. If your "View" is represented by class that is neither sealed nor immutable and you have some way of serializing it, you can make it work, without the "caller" knowing about the serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use a NoSQL database like MongoDB which is schema-less. New fields don't need to be defined up front (no schema modification headaches) and different records can have different fields. This is one of the benefits of a NoSQL store like this.

e.g. in mongo, your "table" could have these 2 records within in legimitely:

```
{
    "ID" : 1,
    "FirstName" : "Joe",
    "LastName" : "Bloggs",
    "FavouriteColour" : "Blue"
}

{
    "ID" : 2,
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Smith",
    "DOB" : "2000-01-01"
}
```

Adding in a new field is as simple as just start including it in records.

In my experience, having a fully flexible/dynamic schema in a RDBMS like SQL Server can be a bit of a pain and be challenging to achieve high performance. I've had experience with options 1) and 3) that you listed. When data was stored as XML, I ended up usually needing to shred the data out into relational form anyway for certain purposes.

Comment: Nice suggestion man, this is my first time hearing this kind of technology. Might use in my on-going project. ^_^

Comment: NoSQL looks promising according my requirement. I never thought I can live without RDBMS :). I'll take a look at mongoDB...

Comment: There are a lot of NoSQL databases out there, all have different approaches (e.g. document databases like MongoDB, Key Value databases like Redis...) so recommend researching the various types and the features/tradeoffs of each one. NoSQL is a big topic, so recommend you get to grips with the full picture before deciding (e.g. you can't do JOINs in MongoDB). Note that RDBMS's aren't going anywhere, they still rock. It's just they offer different things.

Answer (score 1):

It must be said, anything to anyone with full performance is not 100% realistic.

Assuming you're using a relational database, I would go with option #1. You still have the opportunity to take advantage of the storage design that makes an RDBMS quick. You could reduce your security risk by using stored procedures to make your DDL changes, and limit the execute rights on those SPs.

Option 2 can be done, but there could be maintenance problems when trying to figure out if the widget color is stored in UDFText39 or UDFText52.

"Large amount of data" would seem to rule out option 3 unless you go with a non-relational solution. In an RDBMS, that would be quite slow.

Option #4 is an all-around bad idea as you're forced to not only mix data domains (colors, sizes, etc.) but data types as well. Stay away from this one.

Answer (score 0):

i would say that the cleanest solution would be #4.

create a table per datatype you want to use.
- numerivalue
- stringvalue
- datetime value
- ...

so you do not have an incredible huge table and your are strong typed at the same time.
only limitation:
you are limited to a number of supported datatypes. but this is IMHO a natural limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you might to use EF or other ORM framework without modification. You will need custom code, but we like to build new things, are we?

I see two not so bad solutions:

1) Similar like your 1. solution, use 2 tables, one with definition of columns and second for data. For example, your definition table may look like this:

```
 Name       Type    Description
 MyColumn1  int     int column
 MyColumn2  string  string column
```

Data table contains generic named columns filled with actual data.

```
Col1    Col2
1      string 1
2       string 2
```

When you query your "data type" you read "definition" and then query actual data. You can store additional attributes in definition table, like validators...

3) If you are using MS SQL >= 2008, third solution look like good one. I'm still recomending separate table for every "data type".

I don't recomend solution 2, it looks like a bad hack.
Solution 4. looks clean, but that approach isn't appropriate for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this would be a good candidate for the EAV pattern (entity attribute value), which is similar to one of the options you described.

[Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) pattern.

For further reading on a slightly more conceptual level, you could read this article > [Attribute-value-system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-value_system).